# XGBRegressor underestimates sum of regression target (insurance application)

Tags: regression, xgboost

I'm trying to learn how to apply Boostig Algorithms (e.g. XGBoost) to insurance applications (premium calculation). As a starting point I used this [tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_tweedie_regression_insurance_claims.html) from the scikit-learn website.

tldr: The authors use a data set from openml to train two types of models. A Tweedie Regression to directly calculate the so called PurePremium and a Frequency Severity model to separately calculate the claim frequency (Poisson Regression) and claim severity (Gamma Regression). With the product frequency*severity = PurePremium. They evaluate the models on different aspects:

- performance metrics (mean squared error, mean absolute error, mean tweedie deviances with various power parameters)
- observed/predicted total claim amount
- ranking performance from lowest to highest expected claim amount

I downloaded the notebook and added XGBoost regression with a tweedie objective.

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor

# XGBoost can handle non linear relationships between features and target.
# Furthermore it can handle categorical features, therefore we will use
# the untransformed features.
df_train_xgb = df_train.copy()
df_test_xgb = df_test.copy()
categorical_features = ["VehBrand", "VehPower", "VehGas", "Region", "Area"]
numeric_features = ["BonusMalus", "VehAge", "DrivAge", "Density"]

df_train_xgb[categorical_features] = df_train_xgb[categorical_features].astype(
    "category"
)
df_test_xgb[categorical_features] = df_test_xgb[categorical_features].astype("category")

xgb_pure_premium = XGBRegressor(
    objective="reg:tweedie",
    tweedie_variance_power=1.9,
    enable_categorical=True,
    tree_method="gpu_hist",
    max_cat_to_onehot=10,
    random_state=42,
)

xgb_pure_premium.fit(
    df_train_xgb[categorical_features + numeric_features],
    df_train_xgb["PurePremium"],
    sample_weight=df_train["Exposure"],
)
```

The default parameters didn't perform well on any of the above mentioned aspects, therefore I did some hyperparameter optimization on the train data (preprocessing is obtained from the original notebook).

```
from functools import partial, update_wrapper
import logging
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
import optuna
from optuna.samplers import TPESampler
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml


from sklearn.metrics import mean_tweedie_deviance

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, train_test_split
from xgboost import XGBRegressor


# freMTPL2freq dataset from https://www.openml.org/d/41214
df_freq = fetch_openml(data_id=41214, as_frame=True, parser="pandas").data
df_freq["IDpol"] = df_freq["IDpol"].astype(int)
df_freq.set_index("IDpol", inplace=True)

# freMTPL2sev dataset from https://www.openml.org/d/41215
df_sev = fetch_openml(data_id=41215, as_frame=True, parser="pandas").data

# sum ClaimAmount over identical IDs
df_sev = df_sev.groupby("IDpol").sum()

df = df_freq.join(df_sev, how="left")
df["ClaimAmount"].fillna(0, inplace=True)

# unquote string fields
for column_name in df.columns[df.dtypes.values == object]:
    df[column_name] = df[column_name].str.strip("'")

# Note: filter out claims with zero amount, as the severity model
# requires strictly positive target values.
df.loc[(df["ClaimAmount"] == 0) & (df["ClaimNb"] >= 1), "ClaimNb"] = 0

# Correct for unreasonable observations (that might be data error)
# and a few exceptionally large claim amounts
df["ClaimNb"] = df["ClaimNb"].clip(upper=4)
df["Exposure"] = df["Exposure"].clip(upper=1)
df["ClaimAmount"] = df["ClaimAmount"].clip(upper=200000)

# XGBoost can handle non linear relationships between features and target.
# Furthermore it can handle categorical features, therefore we will use
# the untransformed features.
categorical_features = ["VehBrand", "VehPower", "VehGas", "Region", "Area"]
numeric_features = ["BonusMalus", "VehAge", "DrivAge", "Density"]

df[categorical_features] = df[categorical_features].astype("category")

# Insurances companies are interested in modeling the Pure Premium, that is
# the expected total claim amount per unit of exposure for each policyholder
# in their portfolio:
df["PurePremium"] = df["ClaimAmount"] / df["Exposure"]

# This can be indirectly approximated by a 2-step modeling: the product of the
# Frequency times the average claim amount per claim:
df["Frequency"] = df["ClaimNb"] / df["Exposure"]
df["AvgClaimAmount"] = df["ClaimAmount"] / np.fmax(df["ClaimNb"], 1)

df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df, random_state=0)

X_train = df_train[categorical_features + numeric_features]
X_test = df_test[categorical_features + numeric_features]

kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=0)


def objective(trial):
    # define fixed parameters and search space
    trial.set_user_attr("objective", "reg:tweedie")
    trial.set_user_attr("tweedie_variance_power", 1.9)
    trial.set_user_attr("enable_categorical", True)
    trial.set_user_attr("tree_method", "gpu_hist")
    trial.set_user_attr("max_cat_to_onehot", 10)
    trial.set_user_attr("random_state", 42)
    trial.set_user_attr("early_stopping_rounds", 20)
    params = {
        "lambda": trial.suggest_float("lambda", 1e-3, 10.0, log=True),
        "alpha": trial.suggest_float("alpha", 1e-3, 10.0, log=True),
        "colsample_bytree": trial.suggest_float("colsample_bytree", 0.3, 1.0),
        "subsample": trial.suggest_float("subsample", 0.4, 1.0),
        "eta": trial.suggest_float("learning_rate", 0.001, 0.1, log=True),
        "n_estimators": trial.suggest_int("n_estimators", 100, 1000),
        "max_depth": trial.suggest_categorical(
            "max_depth", [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20]
        ),
        "min_child_weight": trial.suggest_int("min_child_weight", 1, 300),
    }
    # callbacks=[XGBoostPruningCallback(trial, "validation_0-tweedie-nloglik@1.01")]
    xgb = XGBRegressor()

    # set fixed parameters and trial parameters
    xgb.set_params(
        **{
            "objective": trial.user_attrs["objective"],
            "tweedie_variance_power": trial.user_attrs["tweedie_variance_power"],
            "random_state": trial.user_attrs["random_state"],
            "enable_categorical": trial.user_attrs["enable_categorical"],
            "tree_method": trial.user_attrs["tree_method"],
            "max_cat_to_onehot": trial.user_attrs["max_cat_to_onehot"],
            "early_stopping_rounds": trial.user_attrs["early_stopping_rounds"],
        }
    )
    xgb.set_params(**params)
    # evaluate model
    test_scores = []

    for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_train):
        X_train_fold, X_test_fold = X_train.iloc[train_index], X_train.iloc[test_index]
        y_train_fold, y_test_fold = (
            df_train["PurePremium"].values[train_index],
            df_train["PurePremium"].values[test_index],
        )
        weights_train_fold, weights_test_fold = (
            df_train["Exposure"].values[train_index],
            df_train["Exposure"].values[test_index],
        )

        eval_metric = update_wrapper(
            partial(
                mean_tweedie_deviance,
                power=1.9,
                sample_weight=weights_test_fold,
            ),
            mean_tweedie_deviance,
        )

        xgb.set_params(eval_metric=eval_metric)

        xgb.fit(
            X_train_fold,
            y_train_fold,
            sample_weight=weights_train_fold,
            eval_set=[(X_test_fold, y_test_fold)],
            # eval_metric=eval_metric,
            verbose=False,
        )

        y_pred_test = xgb.predict(X_test_fold)

        test_scores.append(
            mean_tweedie_deviance(
                y_test_fold, y_pred_test, sample_weight=weights_test_fold, power=1.9
            )
        )

    return np.mean(test_scores)


def model(db, end_time):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    data_db : sqlalchemy.engine.Engine
        Database engine with the data used for training.
    """
    optuna.logging.get_logger("optuna").addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
    study_name = "sklearn_xgboost_20230908"  # Unique identifier of the study.
    storage_name = db
    sampler = TPESampler()
    study = optuna.create_study(
        study_name=study_name,
        storage=storage_name,
        load_if_exists=True,
        sampler=sampler,
    )
    while time.time() < end_time:
        study.optimize(objective, n_trials=1, n_jobs=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        time_delta = 60
    else:
        time_delta = float(sys.argv[1]) * 60

    end_time = time.time() + time_delta
    demo_db = "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/masterthesis"
    model(demo_db, end_time)
```

I applied the "best" set of parameters to the XGBRegressor and rerun the notebook

```
{'alpha': 0.8018296364250094,
 'colsample_bytree': 0.8814562072113403,
 'lambda': 0.08141446031734288,
 'learning_rate': 0.061811999878165116,
 'max_depth': 3,
 'min_child_weight': 289,
 'n_estimators': 538,
 'subsample': 0.8432648125897754}
```

I obtained the following results for the three aspects.

Performance metrics:

[image: Performance Metrics]

Total Claim Amount:

[image: Total Claim Amount]

Ranking Performance:

[image: Ranking Performance]

The Boosting model does well in Performance Metrics (slightly overfitting on the train data) and Ranking Performance, but completely underestimates the Total Claim Amount. I am trying to understand why that is happening (and how it can be prevented), but so far I couldn't find any research with similar problems. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: I used the following to "level" the predictions based on the training data:
```